# role based authguard into infinite loop

Tags: angular, jwt, router

below is my auth.gurad.ts code for canActivate. i want to implement role-based authentication so that when an investor is logged in it should redirect to invester dashboard any help would be apprciated

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            debugger;

             switch(currentUser.role){
                 case 'Business':
                   this.router.navigate(['/business']);

                 break;

                 case 'Invester':
                   this.router.navigate(['/invester']);

                 break;

                 case 'Admin':
                  this.router.navigate(['/admin']);

                 break;


         }

            // check if route is restricted by role
             if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1) {
                 // role not authorised so redirect to home page
                  this.router.navigate(['/']);
                  return false;
              }

            // authorised so return true
            return true;
        }
```

my routing.module.ts code is as below

```
const routes: Routes = [
{   
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
    },
    {   
        path: 'invester',
        component: InvesterComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: [Role.Invester] }
    },
 {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]

    },
```

Comment: In case there are errors displayed on browser cosole please add a screenshot of them in order for others to help

Comment: No error in the console

Comment: Also `Business` route is not added and remove `debugger;` line

Comment: It is there but you can see brackets are not closed

Answer (score 0):

The one that causes the infinite redirecting is your `Route.data`. When you do a `router.navigate` within your Route Guard, It doesn't change the `data` as defined in your `routing.module`.

Say for example, You logged in as an `"Invester"` and your are attempting to get in the URL for `admin`, Your guard does a `this.router.navigate(['/invester'])` but in the next entry to the guard triggered by that navigation, your `route.data.roles` is the same as the initial entry.

```
route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1
```

will always be `true` because `route.data.roles` is always `[Role.Admin]`. And your guard infinitely attempts `this.router.navigate(['/']);`.

I cannot offer a real solution for the meantime but making your role-based-auth-guard trigger navigations other than for a "sign-out" scenario is not advisable. Keep your `canActivate`s and `canLoad`s simple and have your redirection menu for the roles on a separate component and outside where it triggers **before** any of those routing hooks like `canActivate`.